# .NET AWS Serverless project

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

We create a new project and we would like to try to use lambda in aws (functions in azure) and create serverless application. The project for now isn't so big but the project has potencional been huge. Do you think is it a good idea? And can I still use some patterns like cqrs, clean architecture etc.? Because I don't want to write all logic to function handler. But I don't know if it is ok.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is a really broad question unfortunately, which makes it not suitable as a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Also, I don't think that's the intended purpose / use case for `lambda` functions.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary ok i'm sorry. I only like to know opinions for my question. If it's ok build app on lambda functions with another tool.

Comment: @NorSer What do you mean? That the lambda should only be used to perform some specific task? And not to build an application?

Comment: @PetrKasnal I guess it sounds like you want to build a full application with `lambda`, and I'm not sure that's what it was intended for. (I guess I'm thinking you want to build a web app that will allow users to do something) I think it's purpose is to provide a way to run code that otherwise would need to be setup on a server. An example of what I use it for is to ingest messages from SQS into a DB.

Comment: @NorSer yea that's exactly what I meant. I'm sorry, maybe I explained it wrong. First thing this isn't my decision or idea. It was my colleague's idea. And I'm finding out if it's a good idea. And yes i mean whole application. All apis logics. I agree with you that lambdas should only be used for certain tasks. But I have to convince my colleague After all, there are serverless applications that run only in lambdas if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @PetrKasnal Ah, I understand. I would personally go for something like a [JAM Stack](https://www.netlify.com/jamstack/) application architecture. I've used [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com) before for this kind of application. Easy to set up and maintain. I'd start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to use Lambda (serverless functions) for specific functionality and not as a whole application. Lambda has its own limitations when it comes to uptime (15 mins), after which your lambda will have to be triggered again. However, it gives excellent benefit on horizontal scaling, performing the functionality much faster for example when you have to insert messages to SQS queue or dynamodb.
You can build lambda with cqrs, nice architecture, api calls, tests etc as usual. But it is ideal not to dump too many functionalities in single lambda function. Keept it simple.